# Why is chrome caching my html after i started using service workers? (or is it cloudflare?)

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, cloudflare

I started using service workers yesterday and set it to cache only the important js/css files, but it caches the html requests as well. In php, I have this:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

This is the service worker:

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'pokefaith-cache-v1.2';
var urlsToCache = [
  '/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons',
'dependencies_/locals/material.min.js',
'bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  // Perform install steps
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        // IMPORTANT: Clone the request. A request is a stream and
        // can only be consumed once. Since we are consuming this
        // once by cache and once by the browser for fetch, we need
        // to clone the response.
        var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

        return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
          function(response) {
            // Check if we received a valid response
            if(!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
              return response;
            }

            // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
            // and because we want the browser to consume the response
            // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
            // to clone it so we have two streams.
            var responseToCache = response.clone();

            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
              .then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
              });

            return response;
          }
        );
      })
    );
});
```

I want that only those css/js should be cached but I am getting that after reloading a particular page few times, the browser is caching the requests, even though I am pretty sure that my site every time gives a different response.

**EDIT:** Just few days back I also activated cloudflare so is it they who are caching ? But cloudflare say they don't cache html pages, then how is it happening?

Comment: What's running on your webserver? nginx? apache? What version?

Answer (score 1):

You can see full details of the files Cloudflare caches by default [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-). It is possible to cache static html files via [Cloudflare page rules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172256), though from what you describe this seems like an unlikely explanation.

It's easy to check if Cloudflare caching of your service worker files is the problem. Login then from the dashboard choose Domain > Overview > Quick Actions > Development Mode

Good luck